# Getting rowID value for a "checked" checkbox in GridView in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, gridview

I am using checkboxs in a GridView. I need to determine the value in the cell in the 2nd column, if a checkbox has been checked.

I am using C# 2008 and ASP.net

```
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" GridLines="None" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" 
                    onpageindexchanging="gvOrders_PageIndexChanging" ForeColor="#333333">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VerifiedComplete" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbPOID" runat="server"/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PurchaseOrderID" HeaderText="PurchaseOrderID" HtmlEncode="False" ></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="VENDOR_ID" HeaderText="Vendor ID"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="VENDOR_NAME" HeaderText="Vendor Name"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ITEM_DESC" HeaderText="Item Desc"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SYS_DATE" HeaderText="System Date"></asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle CssClass="GridFooter" BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" ForeColor="#333333" BackColor="#FFCC66" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"  />
                    <RowStyle CssClass="GridItem" BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle  CssClass="GridAltItem" BackColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>





        protected void btnDisable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvOrders.Rows)
            {

                if (((CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("cbPOID")).Checked == true)
                {
                    string strPrimaryid = gvr.Cells[2].ToString();
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: Please clarify: "I need to determine the value in the cell in the 2nd column, if a related row checkbox has been checked."
Do you have two checkboxes in the same column in different rows and you want to compare their checked-state? And when/where do you have to compare this?

Comment: No, only one checkbox on the row;

Comment: When you give additional infos to your question you better edit your original question and add them there instead of commenting it.
Where do you need the value and the Checkbox's checked state? Perhaps you should provide some source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this, to avoid accessing the cells of the GridView by index, is to convert the desired BoundField to a TemplateField in the designer.  Then use the FindControl method to get the text value in that cell.  By default, the designer will give the Label control of the new TemplateField a name like "Label1."

I would add some pictures to show the designer part, if that process were easier.  At any rate, the aspx would change like so, which you could do manually too:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="PurchaseOrderID" ...</asp:BoundField>
```

becomes

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PurchaseOrderID">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PurchaseOrderID") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PurchaseOrderID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
 </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then you would make this simple code change:

```
string strPrimaryid = gvr.FindControl("Label1").Text;
```

---

**However**, I think a better way to do this is by utilizing the DataKeys features of the GridView control.  The first step would be to set the DataKeyNames property of your GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" DataKeyNames="PurchaseOrderID" ...>
```

Then, assuming your PurchaseOrderID column is of type int, you would change that same line to be:

```
int primaryid = (int)gvOrders.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Value;
```